# CodevisionAVR typedef

Tags: compiler-errors, typedef, microcontroller

It appears that the Compiler used by CodeVisionAVR handles typedefs in a way I donot understand.

This line of Code is throwing an error:

```
typedef uint64_t offset_t;
```

Error: missing ';'

stdint.h is included so uint64_t is defined.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Other compliers don't seem to have problems with that line. As it should be legal c.

Comment: Gotta ask, are you sure it's that line that's causing the error? Can you share more code where you're declaring the `typedef`? I guess if you comment out that line do you still get the error?

Comment: Oh yes I am sure - so sure that it really messes with my head... The compiler indicates the line. Uncommented there is no error. And the testFile I wrote only consists of includes, this line, and the void main() {while(1);}...

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you declare a variable of that type? Such as `offset_t offset;` You will probably get the same error but will it give you two errors and check the .map file and see if you can see it in there.

Comment: Well I finally found what actually is causing the Problem. Appearantly the compiler uses some different version of <stdint.h>. One without uint64_t. - weird... would never have thought of that

Comment: Ha, I was just about to post that.

Comment: Well most probably this will make things a bit complicated for the whole program^^ but I guess the basic question is solved so I close it. Well thank you BinaryJudy :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to take a look at CodevisionAVR stdint.h and it doesn't include `uint64_t`. If you change it to a `uint32_t` it will work. If you need `uint64_t` then you will have to manually add it to the header file.

Comment: Generally I have to add that the "long long" datatype(for 64 bit integer) is only supported for the "Advanced" or the "Professional" edition of CodeVisionAVR.